# Deleted emails from Gmail go to "Everything Else" Section

Tags: gmail

I get large amounts of emails daily and I have to do a clean up.

I delete unwanted emails.

The problem is some of these emails after being deleted go to "`Everything Else"` Section"

Is there a way to prevent this?  ( or hide `Everything Else` section)?

I tried to hide "Everything Else" under "Manage Labels" but it is not listed there.

Comment: That's not the default Gmail inbox. Are you using Priority Inbox?

Comment: Reference [Priority Inbox - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/186531?hl=en).

Comment: AFAIK deleted emails go to Trash, no to another section or label. Which [Inbox style](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/186534?hl=en) are you using? How are you deleting emails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Everything Else" is part of the Priority Inbox setup.

Unfortunately, that's the one section of Priority Inbox you can't turn off. (See the "Inbox" section of your settings.)

Still, deleted messages shouldn't be going there. Do you see the "Trash" label on messages in that section?

You might want to consider changing to the Default Gmail inbox setup. By automatically categorizing your messages you may find it easier to clean up the unwanted ones.